# IdP and SP per Tenant in WSO2 identity Server using SAML Web SSO

Tags: wso2, simplesamlphp, wso2-identity-server

I am setting up a WSO2 Identity Server at the moment . The first step was to use the resident identity provider in super tenant and setting up service providers as SaaS applications. This worked pretty nice so far.

The bad thing about it is that (1) users need to login by identfying themselves using the `username@tenantdomain` schema. The next bad thing about it is, (2) that we can not configure login policies or account management policies per tenant. We only can handle it globally.

For testing reasons we modified the `authenticationendpoint` application to inject the tenant domain on the fly while logging in (by analyzing `relyingParty` parameter). This worked so far, but point (2) still remains.

Next step was to configure an IdP and SPs per tenant. For my understanding that is the way to get rid of points (1) and (2).

That is where I am completely stuck. The carbon log only mentions that we need to register the SPs in advance. I am reading various posts, jiras issues and blog entries for the last week but I still do not have a working solution. Seems to me that even though I configured the tenants resident IdP and exchanged metadata accordingly the IS still thinks we are trying to communicate with the super tenants resident IdP.

The SPs we are using are created using `SimpleSAMLphp`.

Maybe I missunderstood the principles of setting up IdP/SPs per tenant in WSO2 IS? Maybe I am handling the resident IdPs the wrong way?

Any help/advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is old, below part from [the documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Logging+in+to+WSO2+Products+via+the+Identity+Server) will help whoever searching for an answer.

> From WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 onwards, there are different SAML
>   endpoints for each tenant. If the service provider calls the identity
>   provider's SAML endpoint URL as
>   `https://is.com:9443/samlsso?tenantDomain=foo.com` or the issuer name is
>   appended with `@<TenantDomain>` like `travelocity.com@foo.com`, the SAML
>   requests are directed to the foo.com tenant.

Additionally, note that when using SAML SSO with a tenant (using either of the above methods), the SAML response is signed with the private key of the particular tenant.